# Is it possible to give commands to a running service?

Tags: server, systemd, minecraft

I am running a Minecraft Feed the beast server as a service.

This is my systemd script:

```
[unit]
Description=Een Minecraft Feed The Beast server

[Service]
Environment= MY_ENVIRONMENT_VAR 
WorkingDirectory=/root/ftb_minecraft
ExecStart=/bin/bash ServerStart.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The minecraft server works now.
But I can't input commands. Normaly you get a little server terminal where you can input commands.

Now my question is: Is is still possible to input commands but through some other commands. Something like `systemctl ftb command <Insert command here>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Minecraft server is running in the background, so it is disconnected from the foreground terminal where you might input commands.

It is up to the server to provide a way to interact, such as offering a web-based interface, or a CLI that communicates with the server over a socket.

`systemd` offers the [`sd-bus`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-bus.html) as D-Bus IPC client and the related [busctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html), but they would only be of any use if the server implemented D-Bus.

Summary: Check the docs of your server to see what's possible.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will look in to it to see whats possible.